# If I am applying for a researcher visa (hosting agreement) in Ireland, could my family apply for family visas at the same time?

Tags: working-visas, family, ireland, colombia

I am from Colombia, and I am currently in a recruitment process. I have had 4 interviews and I'm waiting for a formal offer, but it is not clear yet which work permit/visa scheme will be used. As far as I know, if I get a critical skills work permit, my family and I could apply at the same time for visas, so we could travel together. Another option is to apply for a researcher long-stay visa (hosting agreement).

So the first question is: If I am applying for this type of visa for Ireland, could my family apply for family visas at the same time?

Other questions are:

- Is the scheme selected by the company?
- Does it depend on the kind of offer? I mean, the vacancy is "research fellow", but I will be working as a software engineer. I would be a paid worker in an academic-industry project.
- Could I choose which visa to apply for?

Comment: Are you going to be a postgraduate student, paid a stipend, or a worker paid a salary? My guess is the former but you should contact the university's international office and explain your situation as it may be the case that they can apply for the visa that works best for you.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Indeed, I would be a paid worker in an academic-industry project. I have already asked the same question to hr department and I'm waiting for the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR;**

YES

**Detailed response:**

My wife and I applied at the same time. I applied under Hosting Agreement scheme and she under Join Family(non-EEA). I got my visa after 7 weeks approximately and hers was approved 3 weeks after mine.